# Why does this always answer 0 in modulo?

Tags: python

why does this always print leap year, this is just a sample, not yet finished.

```
year = input()
year = int()
if year % 4 == 0:
 print ("leap year")
else :
 print ("not leap year")
```

Comment: what do you think `year = int()` does? If you don't know, read the `int()` doc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign year=int(), you are setting year to zero.

```
>>> print(int.__doc__)
int([x]) -> integer
int(x, base=10) -> integer

Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
are given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point
numbers, this truncates towards zero.

If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the
given base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded
by whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.
Base 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
```